# The equation $a\cos(x) - b = y$, when $y = 0$, implies that the $x$-intercept equals $\cos^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})$. Why?

Tags: trigonometry

Conceptually, I find this confusing.

I would prefer a graphical explanation instead of a algebraic one.

Comment: The x-intercept occurs when $y=0$, hence we need to solve for $x$, given $a\cos x - b= 0$.  This means $a\cos x = b \iff \cos x = \frac ba$, and so $x = \cos^{-1} (\frac ba)$.

Comment: The graph for $\cos x$ and $y$ is a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

The $x$-intercepts of $y=a\cos x -b$ are infinite
$$x=\pm\arccos\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)+2k\pi;\;k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Consider $y=4\cos x-3$. As $y=0$ we have $x=\pm\arccos\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)+k\pi\approx \pm 0.72+2k\pi$.

Some intercepts are $\ldots,-5.56, -0.72, 0.72, 5.56, 7.00,\ldots$.

$$ .$$

[image]